# Delayed ACK at receiver vs. RTO at sender

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

if H1 opens TCP connection to H2, then H1 sends a small packet ( < MSS ) to H2 (H2 is not to respond with data), how long will it take H2 to send a delayed ACK?

How TCP ensures that RTO timer at H1 wouldn't expire before receiving the delayed ACK?

Is it correct understanding that Linux has minimal RTO of 200ms by default, so if network is fast (RTO stays at minimal 200ms) and the data packet is lost on the way from H1 to H2, then H1 will retry in 200ms? If network is slow, then H1 may wait well longer than 200ms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About delayed ACK timing, RFC 1122 says:

> A TCP SHOULD implement a delayed ACK, but an ACK should not
>      be excessively delayed; in particular, the delay MUST be
>      less than 0.5 seconds, and in a stream of full-sized
>      segments there SHOULD be an ACK for at least every second
>      segment.

So it depend on implementation and of course if could reduce application performance.
In linux kernel they do not send delayed ACK by timer or fixed interval as you can see in following code they behave differently by conditions.
As you can see in `net/ipv4/tcp_input.c`, they says in comment:

> There is something which you must keep in mind when you analyze the
>    behavior of the tp->ato delayed ack timeout interval.  When a
>    connection starts up, we want to ack as quickly as possible.  The
>    problem is that "good" TCP's do slow start at the beginning of data
>    transmission.  The means that until we send the first few ACK's the
>    sender will sit on his end and only queue most of his data, because
>    he can only send snd_cwnd unacked packets at any given time.  For
>    each ACK we send, he increments snd_cwnd and transmits more of his
>    queue.  -DaveM

```
static void tcp_event_data_recv(struct sock *sk, struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    struct tcp_sock *tp = tcp_sk(sk);
    struct inet_connection_sock *icsk = inet_csk(sk);
    u32 now;

    inet_csk_schedule_ack(sk);

    tcp_measure_rcv_mss(sk, skb);

    tcp_rcv_rtt_measure(tp);

    now = tcp_time_stamp;

    if (!icsk->icsk_ack.ato) {
        /* The _first_ data packet received, initialize
         * delayed ACK engine.
         */
        tcp_incr_quickack(sk);
        icsk->icsk_ack.ato = TCP_ATO_MIN;
    } else {
        int m = now - icsk->icsk_ack.lrcvtime;

        if (m <= TCP_ATO_MIN / 2) {
            /* The fastest case is the first. */
            icsk->icsk_ack.ato = (icsk->icsk_ack.ato >> 1) + TCP_ATO_MIN / 2;
        } else if (m < icsk->icsk_ack.ato) {
            icsk->icsk_ack.ato = (icsk->icsk_ack.ato >> 1) + m;
            if (icsk->icsk_ack.ato > icsk->icsk_rto)
                icsk->icsk_ack.ato = icsk->icsk_rto;
        } else if (m > icsk->icsk_rto) {
            /* Too long gap. Apparently sender failed to
             * restart window, so that we send ACKs quickly.
             */
            tcp_incr_quickack(sk);
            sk_mem_reclaim(sk);
        }
    }
    icsk->icsk_ack.lrcvtime = now;

    tcp_ecn_check_ce(tp, skb);

    if (skb->len >= 128)
        tcp_grow_window(sk, skb);
}
```

Comment: Well, implementation is linux (latest kernel). And yes, I read the RFC.

Comment: You want to know the specific value of implementation in linux kernel ?

Comment: I add some comments and codes from linux kernel and I hope they could helped you.

Comment: Thanks for this. But what is the sender behavior? How long does it wait before resending, if no ack from the receiver? The whole rto?

Comment: This is a input behaviour of TCP, if you want you can see `net/ipv4/tcp_output.c`, I think you can found your answers there